# Background image over images with position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So on the page that I will show you I have the `<div class="bg-over">` this div has a background image, and I need it to be over those sliding images, it's a noise effect image.

You can have a look here: http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/ any sugestions?

//LE

```
  <div class="home-featured-bg">
    <div class="bg-over">
    <div class="absolute">
         <div class="slide"><img src="<?php echo PATH; ?>/images/content/bg-1.jpg"/></div>
         <div class="slide"><img src="<?php echo PATH; ?>/images/content/bg-2.jpg"/></div>
         <div class="slide"><img src="<?php echo PATH; ?>/images/content/bg-3.jpg"/></div>
    </div><!-- end .absolute-->
   </div><!-- end bg-over-->
  </div><!-- end home-featured-bg-->
```

css

```
.bg-over{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1;background-image:url(../images/bg-agenda.png);}
```

Comment: What's the problem, and what have you tried?

Comment: The problem is that the background image is not over the slides(the images) and I can't find a workaround

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a background image render on top of elements that are children of the element containing the background image. What you need to do is apply the background image to another child of the wrapper and then position that on top of all other elements. This may not work for you though as it will prevent interaction with the elements beneath it.

I've long wished for a foreground-image property.

Comment: Look at my post now, I move the div `bg-over` inside the wrapper, but still doesn't work...god I'm going crazy, I'm trying to find a solution for about 2h now

Comment: Make sure the `position` of `home-featured-bg` is not `static` (which is the default). Try `relative` instead. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by placing the div over the holder div for the slides

```
<div class="bg-over">
  <!-- agenda loading -->
</div><!-- end bg-over-->


  <div class="home-featured-bg">
    <div class="absolute">
         <div class="slide"><img src="<?php echo PATH; ?>/images/content/bg-1.jpg"/></div>
         <div class="slide"><img src="<?php echo PATH; ?>/images/content/bg-2.jpg"/></div>
         <div class="slide"><img src="<?php echo PATH; ?>/images/content/bg-3.jpg"/></div>
    </div><!-- end .absolute-->
  </div><!-- end home-featured-bg-->
```